# How to stop wyBuild from overwriting files on update?

Tags: wybuild

I have inherited a project that uses wyBuild and wyUpdate to perform automatic updates of the app. There was only one version of the project, the Production version, which has certain server settings hard-coded into it when it's compiled, which is appropriate as these settings must never be changed in Production.

I now have a need to build a Test version of the project, to be able to test new changes without affecting any production systems. I have successfully built a Test version to connect to our Test server.

The installer installs a configuration file, and then prompts the user for each configuration value (but no server settings, these are internal and hard-coded). This only ever happens on install. It can't be reconfigured from the app, nor does it get triggered during an update.

The problem is that when running wyUpdate to update to the latest version of the app, Production and Test behave differently. In Production, updating the app keeps the configuration file, while in Test, the configuration file is overwritten, thereby losing all the mandatory fields. This file has to be reconfigured by hand before the app will start working again, which is beyond the technical level of our customers.

How does wyBuild skip overwriting the config file on update? How can I replicate this in the Test version?

The maximum number of changes I can make in Production without first verifying them in Test is zero, so I can't solve this problem (yet) by changing the way the configuration file is handled.

Answer (score 0):

The previous programmers were using different files to build the installer and the update patch files. The config file would change in the installer, but they made sure it didn't change between patch versions by copying the same file to each previous directory.

Since the configuration file should **never** be patched, it can safely be removed, but only if it's removed from all patches, not just the latest one.

Remove the config file from ALL previous versions (wyBuild => Files & Folders, select each tab in turn, select the config file, press X Delete, => Build wyUpdate & Updates => Build updates! Done!

Now, no config file will even be looked at when an update it performed!